# ASP Identity - Accessing HttpContext on a reference library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to move my ASP Identity logic to another project inside my solution.

Everything is fine except the fact that I cannot access `HttpContext` inside my reference library. I need to access `HttpContext` to seed my database using the `ApplicationUserManager`.

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {            
        var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();

        // Create here users and roles using userManager and roleManager
    }
}
```

So the question is : How to access `ApplicationUserManager` and `ApplicationRoleManager` without `HttpContext`, or how can I access `HttpContext` here.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I would suggest a slightly different approach. The Identity team committed what I consider a bit of a mortal sin in bootstrapping the sample with a makeshift dependency injection container based on OWIN. Dependency injection is a great idea, but not like this. Understandably different developers prefer different DI containers, which makes creating a sample project based on a real DI container a bit of a no-go, but they should have refrained from utilizing dependency injection in the sample project and simply recommended the use of dependency injection and perhaps given guidance to implement this with various containers.

All that said, the only thing `HttpContext` is being used for here is to get the OWIN context, and that alone is being used to handle their half-baked dependency injection for Identity. So, if you simply inject your own `UserManager` with your DI container of choice, you remove the dependency on `HttpContext` and you're good to go.

You just need to provide configuration for two things: `UserManager` and `IUserStore`. Tell your DI container how to inject those, and then you can just add a dependency on `UserManager` in your library class constructor and you're ready to roll.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will upvote but not accept as answer since I used another approach.

Comment: @Chris Pratt. I like your answer and makes sense. Sorry to be a bother, but I have been stuck for 2 days trying to do the same.I am new to DI containers. Would you be kind enough to point me in the direction of some example doing finding UserManager in my C# Library, i.e. How cxan I DI UserManager and IUserStore, and then getting the UserManager in any C# Library to use in MVC 5?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I was able to access it by doing :

```
public static void InitializeIdentityForEF(IdentityDbContext db)
{
    var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(db));
    var roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new ApplicationRoleStore(db));
}
```

Comment: I was happy with this solution, however the separation of code _is_ a caveat to consider.