# Accessing ASP.NET Identity Data from DataAccess Layer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have an n-tiered solution that uses MVC-WebApi, Owin, ASP.NET Identity and EntityFramework. I used the sample Identity code as a starter and added some custom properties to the ApplicationUser.  I've also configured all of the classes to use Guids for Identity values.  All working great so far.

I started having difficulty when I wanted to move the IdentityConfig and IdentityModel files from the sample code out of the MVC project and to the DataAccess project.  These files define several key classes such as ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationRoleManager, etc.  Within the ApplicationDbInitializer, there is code to get the ApplicationUserManager and ApplicationRoleManager using the current HttpContext for the purpose of seeding the database.  It seems pretty unnecessary to require an HttpContext to seed the database. Also, there are other background process that I will be adding soon that will need to access Identity data from the business layer without an HttpContext being relevant, so I'd like to get that dependency removed now.

I saw the Q&A on this subject [ASP Identity - Accessing HttpContext on a reference library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162026/asp-identity-accessing-httpcontext-on-a-reference-library), but the best answer was pretty thin. I tried replacing

```
var userManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var roleManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
```

with

```
var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(db));
var roleManager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole, Guid, IdentityUserRole>(db));
```

but that REALLY lead down a rabbit hole.  The code wouldn't compile unless I defined custom implementations of every Identity class  and implemented interfaces for them, etc. It needed all of the following (possibly more, I didn't get it finished)

- ApplicationUserRole: IdentityUserRole
- ApplicationRole : IdentityRole, IRole
- ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim
- ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin

and IRole needed to be fully implemented, which I'm not sure how to do.

I stopped at this point because it feels like there should be an easier way or some sample code I can look at. I don't really need anything customized beyond ApplicationUser. Am I going down the right path here or is my gut correct and there's a better way?

Comment: Probably not a solution to your problem, but you can access your users data via your DbContext without the need for UserManager. I found this approach (using the `UserManager` and 'RoleManager' only for its  methods for authentication, registration, tokens etc. while using my dbContext for all the other, including CRUD operations) to be much easier, and without going deep in rabbit holes that Identity sometimes have.

Comment: That's pretty much the conclusion I've reached. Ideally, I'm hoping someone can come up with a real answer to the original question, but if not I'll just backtrack and put the Identity Models back in the MVC project.